# How to auto configure `MetricsModule` using `JacksonAutoConfiguration` in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jackson

I'm trying to use `MetricsModule` to parse the response body of `/metrics` endpoint. For some reason the module never gets registered with the respective `ObjectMapper`.

I've found that this `@PostConstruct` method gets erased:

```
@PostConstruct
private void More ...registerModulesWithObjectMappers() {
    Collection<Module> modules = getBeans(this.beanFactory, Module.class);
    for (ObjectMapper objectMapper : getBeans(this.beanFactory, ObjectMapper.class)) {
    objectMapper.registerModules(modules);
}
```

I've implemented my own code to do the same thing, but I'm not sure if this is the correct way to fix this issue.

Why wouldn't `JacksonAutoConfiguration` support this type of auto-configuration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That method was removed in commit ["Don't register Jackson Module beans with all ObjectMappers"](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/commit/5e4a74562066b77ef37ed0b9ed0fc1533ad93b9b) for issue ["Make Jackson auto-configuration more consistent and predictable"](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/2489). In short, it was done to not mess up with every `ObjectMapper` bean in the container.

To ensure that your `Module` bean gets registered with auto-configured `ObjectMapper`, make sure `Module` creation does not depend on an instance of `ObjectMapper` in any way. For example, do not autowire auto-configured `ObjectMapper` anywhere before `Module` bean is created.